# Windows Authentication for polars connectorx SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, windows-authentication, python-polars

[Can we connect to SQL server using polars and connectorx? YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74967574/connect-python-polars-to-sql-server-no-support-currently)

The username I used in SQL Server Management Studio right after the below test without issue.

```
conn = 'mssql+pyodbc://username@server/database?driver=SQL+Server''&trusted_connection=yes'
cx.read_sql(conn,query)
```

> [2023-01-01T19:12:44Z ERROR tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed
> for user 'user'. code=18456 [2023-01-01T19:12:44Z ERROR
> tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed for user 'user'. code=18456
> [2023-01-01T19:12:45Z ERROR tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed
> for user 'user'. code=18456 [2023-01-01T19:12:47Z ERROR
> tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed for user 'user'. code=18456
> [2023-01-01T19:12:51Z ERROR tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed
> for user 'user'. code=18456 [2023-01-01T19:12:57Z ERROR
> tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed for user 'user'. code=18456
> [2023-01-01T19:13:10Z ERROR tiberius::tds::stream::token] Login failed
> for user 'user'. code=18456 Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "", line 1, in File
> "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\connectorx_init_.py",
> line 224, in read_sql result = _read_sql( RuntimeError: Timed out in
> bb8

Do I need to reconfigure my connection string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, per [SQL Server Windows Authentication Connectorx](https://github.com/sfu-db/connector-x/issues/233)

Try dropping pyodbc for connectorx connection strings.

```
conn = 'mssql://server/database?trusted_connection=true'
cx.read_sql(conn,query)
```

Also recommend for SQL Server Authentication

```
conn ="mssql://Username:Password@Server/Database?driver=SQL+Server"
```

Comment: I see in your connection strings for Connectorx you have not specified the host port.  Does this assume the port is 1433?